# Why does the itune store webservice returns nothing for iphone apps?

Tags: web-services

I read the guide

http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html

and tried

```
http://ax.phobos.apple.com.edgesuite.net/WebObjects/MZStoreServices.woa/wa/itmsSearch?limit=100&term=finance&output=json&media=all&entity=software&country=us
```

it returns nothing, why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try this: http://ax.phobos.apple.com.edgesuite.net/WebObjects/MZStoreServices.woa/wa/**wsSearch**?limit=100&term=finance&output=json&media=all&entity=software&country=us